# Why does appending a TR markup with a whitespace or linebreak before it, causes it to be outside the tbody?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, append

I've came across a curious behavior in appending a `<tr>` string markup to a table through JQuery. Everytime I appended row that I was generating as a string, it was been placed outside my `tbody`. Then I found out the issue.

It works fine if I append it like this:

```
$("table").append("<tr><td>Test</td></tr>");
```

But, if I add a whitespace or a line break before the `<tr>`, it appends the row outside the `tbody`.

```
$("table").append(" <tr><td>Test</td></tr>");
$("table").append("\n<tr><td>Test</td></tr>");
```

Funny is that, if I use any other character, it still works fine. **Is there any particular reason for this behavior?**

```js
//Works fine without anything before the tr
$("table").append("<tr><td>Second row</td></tr>");

//Works fine also with any character
$("table").append("sdfa<tr><td>Third row</td></tr>");

//Doesn't work when there's an whitespace or newline
$("table").append(" <tr><td>Fourth row</td></tr>");
$("table").append("\n<tr><td>Fifth row</td></tr>");
```

```css
table tbody td {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a helper utility in jQuery, `manipulationTarget`, that determines the `target` for where to append the string. Specifically:

```
function manipulationTarget( elem, content ) {
    return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "table" ) &&
        jQuery.nodeName( content.nodeType !== 11 ? content : content.firstChild, "tr" ) ?

        elem.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0] ||
            elem.appendChild( elem.ownerDocument.createElement("tbody") ) :
        elem;
}
```

What happens is when you pass in a string with `whitespace` at the beginning, it creates a document fragment where the first child is a `text` node, not `tr`. The gibberish text (`sdfa`) is removed in another utility method.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is according to jQuery documentation

> .append( content [, content ] )
>
> content   Type: **htmlString** or **Element** or **Array** or **jQuery   DOM
>   element**, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at
>   the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Where [*htmlString*](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) is identified as HTML if it starts with `<tag ... >`

Comment: These docs uses the example that `$( "bye<b>hello</b>" ).appendTo( "body" );` is invalid. But it works in my example (See third row). Why specifically whitespace?